# Simulation of error function gives wrong plot

Tags: debugging, plot, fortran, fortran90

I was trying to write a Fortran program which would simulate the error function and give a list of its values for different values of x. It did give a list which was initially correct. However, as I extended the domain, I saw that it converged to 0.885 whereas it should have converged to 1.

The code is as follows:

```
  Program erf_func_calc
    Real:: y,z,h,w
    Integer:: i,a
    h=0.0001
    open(1,file='error_function_calculator.txt',status='unknown')
    write(1,*) 'x','                  ','erf(x)'
    write(1,*) '0','                   ','0.00'
    z=0.0
    Do a=1,40000
      y=a*h
      w=-y*y
      z=z+h*exp(w)
      write(1,*) y,'                ',z,'               ',exp(w)
    End do
    close(1)
  End program erf_func_calc
```

If you want, I can give you a snapshot of the list where it converges.

This is the graph that I obtained from those values:

[image: screenshot with the graph]

Where does my program go wrong?

Comment: @VladimirF But double precision will cause changes in the third or fourth places of decimal. Here, we are talking about 0.8 and 1.0 .... a difference of 0.2

Comment: It is better to use higher numerical precision variables, but it does not change the result that much here. Avoid file units less or equal to 10.

Comment: It's looks like you're trying to calculate the answer by applying the rectangle rule to integrate, yes?

Comment: It is not always that obvious, especially when you are summing up small numbers!

Comment: @francescalus Almost, but not exactly the rectangle rule.. as you can see..

Comment: @VladimirF How do file units matter? less or more than 10??

Comment: They do not matter here at all. But in general some units, generally less than 10, most often 0,5 and 6, are pre-connected for special purposes. It was a general recommendation, not a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calculating the error function: you are calculating the error function [scaled by half the square root of pi](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).  This scaling factor is about `0.886`.

Fortran 2008 introduced the intrinsic function `erf`, should you wish to check your answer in more detail.